# Character build for Gandalf in D&D3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

In my groups next campaign I am hoping to be a PC instead of the DM and I want to play a character who is like Gandalf from *The Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit*. I began looking at options; he would probably be a bard, but what race would he be? I want him to be proficient with a sword, and he should have lots of knowledge skills, etc.

I am looking to model him from the Gandalf from the actual books, I'm not overtly worried about his power level.

So I am wondering basically how would I recreate Gandalf in D&D 3.5 terms?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gandalf is *not* mechanically a wizard, actually; he's got the Knowledge skills but no spellbook, no evidence of memorizing spells, and the spells he casts are few and far between. And as you point out, he's not inept with a sword. He does fireworks, both mundane and magical, tells stories, sings songs, knows the most random things, and spends most of his time getting other people to do things for him: **Gandalf's a bard.** (Not an answer because I can't offer any specific advice re: Gandalf the Bard's build.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Build him by feel

SevenSidedDie has an excellent answer about why there's no definitive Gandalf build, but I think we can talk constructively about how to go creating *a* Gandalf build.

You want to "recreate Gandalf from the books" "in D&D3.5 terms." You can't, not precisely. D&D isn't a good fit at all for actually recreating LotR scenarios or characters: it has a different mythos, a different philosophy toward magic, and is built with mechanical considerations that Tolkien didn't have to worry about.

But we can create D&D characters who are *like* LotR characters. This is going to require choosing what to keep or emphasize, and what isn't as important so it can be left behind or diminished. We won't be making a character who can accomplish exactly what Gandalf could accomplish --no more, no less-- in the novels. We'll be making a Gandalf who is Gandalf in essence rather than in detail.

### What defines Gandalf to *you*?

Because of the limitations of D&D build options, you'll have to focus on one particular "kind" of Gandalf. Deciding what kind of Gandalf you want to design needs to be deliberate and purposeful, and you'll need to own that decision.

If you were asked to describe Gandalf in a phrase of five words or less, what would you say? If he's an "ancient, angelic guardian of hope," you're going to build him differently than if he's a "crafty and manipulative magical hobo." Both are absolutely true descriptions of him, but each emphasize a different element of his character.

#### What does this say about race and/or templates?

Gandalf could be a human, an aasimar, a half-celestial, or a number of other choices depending on what kind of Gandalf you've chosen to make. Don't be concerned about whether it's an accurate representation of a Maia clothed in mortal flesh; get the race or template that best reflects the phrase that describes your personal Gandalf.

#### What does this say about how he gets things done?

What are your Gandalf's goals and how does he accomplish them? Does he ride a white horse at dawn to bring hope to the hopeless, or does he throw flaming pinecones at wolves? Is he a self-sacrificial hero or a guy who pranks his friends by throwing a party at their house without telling them?

The answers to this question will tell you a lot about his class and build. I think of Gandalf as a guy who gets other people to do things, but can handle himself in a pinch, so I consider him a bard.

### Don't be afraid to go off canon

If your Gandalf is a powerful spellcaster, forget trying to map his powers in the books to D&D spells. Make him a powerful spellcaster by D&D standards, so he is deserving of the proper eldritch respect.

This is the essence of my advice: **Don't try to recreate what Gandalf can do.** Recreate the essence of who he is and what he means. At the end of the day we don't remember him as the level 5 human wizard who cast *shatter* on a bridge; we remember him as the man who sacrificed himself to a terrible monster so his friends could get away.

Comment: Nice answer! "Gandalf in essence rather than in detail" is perfect.

Comment: +1 for the awesome answer and " crafty and manipulative magical hobo" Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 36):

On a day in 1974, D&D was published in three little books. I'm equally certain that later that week someone asked what Gandalf's character sheet would look like, and it's been debated ever since in *Dragon Magazine*'s articles (most notably [Gandalf was a Fifth-Level Magic User](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?300886-Gandalf-was-only-a-Fifth-Level-Magic-User!) by Bill Seligman published in The Dragon, which became Dragon magazine, in issue #5, March 1977) and Letters to the Editor, early Usenet arguments, later web forums like [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?346654-What-level-are-Gandalf-and-Sauron) and [Dragonsfoot](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=192409&sid=9447f736698a92136712477e44224cd3#p192409), and around tables across the world without satisfactory resolution. It's such an old debate that [it's now a joke](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showpost.php?p=14678650&postcount=853).

The problem is that Gandalf is not a D&D character. He has abilities that cannot be adequately described by any set of classes, feats, spells, non-weapon proficiencies, prestige classes, kits, hybrids, skills, or magic items in *any* edition of D&D, let alone whichever is currently being considered. Many people have tried, and for every proposed Gandalf character put forth, there have been a dozen other people who disagree with its details.

The answer to this question is "However the tales of Gandalf inspire you to make a character," which will necessarily be different for each person. This is, inherently, an unanswerable question beyond that simple answer.

Comment: +1 for "Gandalf is not a D&D character". Gandalf's magic works quite differently than a D&D wizard's magic and so he cannot be represented as one.

Answer (score 6):

LOTR is an inherently low magic setting vs D&D's high magic setting. In D&D nobody bats an eye at magic users throwing out all kinds of crazy powers (magic missile, burning hands, frost cone), but in the books (and even in PJ's LOTR movies) you very rarely see any magic and when you do it's always very subtle (Gandalf's staff as a light in Moria, Galadrial's phial, and of course the rings like the One Ring). In my opinion most of the magic is interwoven into places (Lothlorien, Rivendell, Minal Morgal)  or things (the rings, sting, the staff, the horn of Gondor) versus being something characters manipulate and use like a tool. Also Gandalf is very handy with conventional weapons (his sword; Glamdring) and fighting despite being an old man & a wizard. Gandalf should be primarily a melee class with only a few levels in a magic class and possibly a vow if you RP him not wearing armor.

Comment: Please note that due of the nature of his mission, Gandalf never openly reveal all his power. The Istari were supposed not to act directly, but instead of that, influence Middle Earth people to win their battles. So, Gandalf's magic is sure more powerful than summoning some light or burning some orcs (like he did in the Hobbit). But you are right, he was very skilled with the sword (he also had a very powerful blade). It's not surprising, since Istari are good at whatever they try, even smoking.

Answer (score 5):

Gandalf is a Maia, that is, a divine spirit helper to the Valar, the Tolkien's "gods". In his nature, he is similar to Sauron, except that Sauron was corrupted by the evil "god" Melkor.

Upon arriving Middle Earth, Gandalf and his companion (Saruman, Radagast, and the two Blue Mages) took human appearance, even human traits (good and bad traits).

So, I'd make the character human, since this is the flesh that the Istari adquired. Also, because in the two mentioned fictions, Gandalf seems human, so I think that way is closer to what you are looking to mimic.

I'd think about choosing the Sorcerer class, as Magic is innate in Gandalf, and not based on knowledge.