# How do I build Riddick?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Just came back from *Riddick* and I loved it. Less than *Chronicles of Riddick*, I am afraid, but enjoyable still.

I would like a 20-level build for Riddick based on these criteria:

#### Concept: Hardy survivalist who strikes from the shadows

- Night-optimized, okay to be at the expense of daytime ability.
- Specializes in blades (melee a must; also ranged if possible).
- Good at Intimidation
- Will save is not a viable dump area.
- Affinity with animals a bonus, but not necessary.
- If the "Riddick feel" is best gained by a sub-optimal feature choice, I'd rather have a slightly less Riddick-like but mechanically superior feature.

I want to emphasize intelligence, tactics and stealth killing. Riddick might be a savage, but he is a very clever savage. It's not that I want him to be a wanted man, but 1v1 he would hold his own against pretty much anything of similar CR.

The 3.5 Assassin prestige class is the kind of thing I'm thinking of, but the Pathfinder version seems subpar. I am not afraid of a spellcaster build, nor dipping into barbarian.

Materials: only paizo content from the website. no custom anything.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/23107/4398), and hop in chat to talk about how to write your question if you want an answer that's usefully different.

Comment: A Ranger might well be a good fit

Comment: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m5vk?Riddick-in-Pathfinder looks like it suggests human or half-orc with pass for human as race. For class it looks like urban ranger/rogue.

Comment: Riddick as a 3.5 character. http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=144652

Comment: I'd say ask Vin Diesel. He based Riddick on a D&D character he once played. Not sure if he was 3.5e though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping to have seen the new movie before answering just in case some whacky new things were added.  No matter which class you pick, you need to pretty much get great stat rolls to begin with and maybe even a custom race.

Ranger is definitely the class I'd go for at first due to the innate survival skills, but my mind takes a very specific turn: **go Monk**

Monks possess all the stealth skills, have the best saves, respectable BAB, and Flurry is like two weapon fighting rules for the unarmed.  The only downside is the alignment requirement, but to a monk being Lawful means strictly adhering to your dojo's code.

Comment: I have lost faith in pure 20 base classes in 3.5, but I see it is highly encouraged in Pathfinder.

Comment: Multiclassing (IMHO) just messes with your skills, which at higher level you have to max out to stand a chance against any comparable adversary.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to recommend an Ranger or a classic rogue. Ranger would satisfy your want for an animal affinity. You could potentially multi-class the two as well.

You could also try a dark elf as well. (For the night vision aspect) I'm not overly familiar with 3.5E's class roles but if you are looking into it, I would suggest going with a multi-classed rogue and ranger. If I recall correctly that's fine when you are using 3.5E.

Answer (score -1):

you can also choose the half orc template if the dm lets you to still be human, he has darkvision str bonus and sensibility to light and im thinking ranger barbarian or rogue barbarian or all 3